# Accuweather npm in Vuejs

Tags: npm, vuejs2

Is there anyone here used npm accuweather in vuejs2? It will be look something like this. I already have API for developer

[image]

Comment: This is a job / help wanted post? if yes, this is the first time i see it (it seems a fun project to do), its the API public?

Comment: need help on it @Ethaan if there's something something related to it.

Comment: i will be happy to help, anyways i was looking right now a pet project to work on @Alyssa Reyes

Comment: did you make this @Alyssa Reyes